# Unique Limit Theorem Proof Check (using neighborhood method)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Definition of a Neighborhood: Let $\vec x \in \mathbb R ^{n}$, then the neighborhood of a $\vec x$ is simply an open set $\scr U$ containing $\vec x$

Definition of a Limit: Let $f: A \subset \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$, where $A$ is an open set. Let $\vec x_{0} \in A$ or be a boundary point of $A$, and let $N$ be the neighborhood of $\vec b \in \mathbb R^{m}.$Then $f(\vec x)$ approaches $\vec b$ if there exists an neighborhood $U$ of $\vec x_0$ such that $\vec x \neq \vec x_0$ and $\vec x \in U$ and $\vec x \in A$ implies that $f(\vec x)\in N$.

> Theorem 
>   If  $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(\vec x)= \vec b_1$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(\vec x)= \vec b_2$ then $b_1 = b_2.$

**Is the following proof correct?**

*Proof.*
*Assume that if $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(\vec x)= \vec b_1$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(\vec x)= \vec b_2$ then $b_1 \neq b_2.$*
*Let $f: A \subset \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$, where $A$ is an open set. Let $\vec x_{0} \in A$ or be a boundary point of $A$,let $N_1$ be the neighborhood of $\vec b_1 \in \mathbb R^{m}$ and $N_2$ be the neighborhood of $\vec b_2 \in \mathbb R^{m}$ .Then $f(\vec x)$ approaches $\vec b_1$ and $f(\vec x)$ approaches $\vec b_2$, if there exists an neighborhood $U$ of $\vec x_0$ such that $\vec x \neq \vec x_0$ and $\vec x \in U$ and $\vec x \in A$ implies that $f(\vec x)\in N_1$ and $f(\vec x)\in N_1$.*

*For all $f(\vec x)\in N_1$ $\Longrightarrow$ $f(\vec x)\in N_2$ and similarly $f(\vec x)\in N_2$ $\Longrightarrow$  $f(\vec x)\in N_1$.*

*Therefore, $N_1= N_2$ and $b_1 = b_2.$*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in the proof, especially in the last step. I suggest the following proof:

If $b_1 \neq b_2$, then we can find a neighbourhood $N_1$ of $b_1$ and a neighbourhood $N_2$ of $b_2$ such that $N_1 \cap N_2 = \varnothing$. For $N_2$, we can find a neighbourhood of $x_0$, such that $x \in (U - \{x_0\}) \cap A \implies f(x) \in N_2$. Also for $N_1$, we can find a neighbourhood $U'$ of $x_0$, such that $x \in (U' - \{x_0\}) \cap A \implies f(x) \in N_1$. Taking $U'' = U \cap U'$ (which is nonempty), we find that $x \in (U'' - \{x_0\}) \cap A) \implies f(x) \in N_1 \cap N_2$, which leads to a contradiction provided that $(U'' - \{x_0\}) \cap A \neq \varnothing$.